# jQuery's filter using functions returning value is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to select tags with elements of its tag name around
consider

```
<dt id="term-1">term 1</dt>
<dd>definition 1-a</dd>
<dd>definition 1-b</dd>
<dd>definition 1-c</dd>
<dd>definition 1-d</dd>
<dt id="term-2">term 2</dt>
<dd>definition 2-a</dd>
<dd>definition 2-b</dd>
<dd>definition 2-c</dd>
<dt id="term-3">term 3</dt>
<dd>definition 3-a</dd>
<dd>definition 3-b</dd>
```

To select all `<dd>`s without the first element is

```
$("dd").nextUntil(":not(dd)")
```

But if I want to select without being constrained to `<dd>` only, I want to use

```
$(*).nextUntil(function () {
    return ":not(" + this.tagName + ")";
})
```

The returned value is exactly what I want, ie. `:not(DD)`. But I am not able to select anything in this case. why?

Comment: [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) does take a filter function for the tested elements, not one that returns a selector.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `nextUntil` function takes in a selector string, not a handling anonymous function.  You should specify a selector string instead of a function

Comment: But I don't know the name. I want to make a wild selection.

Comment: Theoretically, the anonymous function return the correct string. Why nextUntil is not taking it?

Comment: Mate, but that's what I mean...remove the function

Comment: `$('*').nextUntil(':not(' + this.tagName + ')');`

Comment: what's the difference in nature of a string returned by an anonymous function and a string alone?

Answer (score 0):

How about `$('*:not(first-child)')`?

Comment: Protip: `*` selector (and `:not()` without class/id/element selector) is extremely inefficient.

Comment: it doesn't exclude the first element of the tag cluster

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to select.  Everything except `definition 1-a`?

Comment: Eventually I want to merge adjacent <p>s and <div>s with same class values to form bigger tags. Any idea?

Comment: Earlier you said you want to select elements and exclude something, not to merge.  I am confused.  Please use your HTML to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the digression. I want to select the elements of same type excluding the first element in their localized area.
As the example provided, I want to all <dd>s excluding definition 1-a, definition 2-a, definition 3-a. Your solution will only exclude definition 1-a

Comment: `$('dd + dd')` should do that in your case.

Comment: But I want to pass in multiple types. Not limited to dd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43701/discussion-between-punund-and-user1978421)

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I didn't mean to give you more trouble. I will find some work around. I just wondered if there would be cleverer query commands.
Thanks for your help.
But $("dd + dd") does simplify the query

Comment: since you are so good at css query, I just want to ask one more question. Is it possible to specify the following tag to have the same attribute value as the first one has as $([attr] + [attr]) in $('dd+dd') way?